# RSA SecurID development with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, rsa, securid

I'm trying to develop using asp and c#. Is there any .Net support for implementing RSA SecurID Authentication?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to use the "RSA SecurID Software Token for Web SDK" found [here](http://www.emc.com/security/rsa-securid/rsa-securid-software-authenticators/web-sdk.htm).